# Page not in correct size or format

Tags: landscape, musixtex

Total newbie here: please bear with me. I’m running *TeXShop* on a Mac, trying to render a single-page musical score that uses the “bagpipe” macro-package. The file starts with

```
%&bagpipe
\input bagpipe
%
% RowanTree.tex 
%
\newpitch\newgrace\noautoglue
%
\ifx\medleyflag\relax\else\widewidth\nopagenumbers\fi
%
\landscape
```

I take it the last line is supposed to set up the page in landscape format, but the output is in portrait format (with the content upright), and half the score runs off the page. Moreover when I open the PDF in an application that reveals content outside the media box, I can see more notes, bar-lines, &c. but the staves for that part of the score are missing. Since the remaining content is actually some 16" wide, I guess it was supposed to fit on ledger or A3 paper rather than letter or A4.

I have tried adding various snippets involving {geometry}, but they all caused errors like

```
/RowanTree.tex:11: Undefined control sequence.
l.11 \usepackage
                [landscape]{geometry}
```

which if bypassed (by typing R in the console) resulted in the command line being typeset in the document. I also tried changing the paper size in *TeXShop*’s File > Page Setup menu to no avail.

Note that I’ve only been able to get even this far using the “Plain TeX” engine: using the default “LaTeX” on the original file caused an “Undefined control sequence” error that prevented any output from being produced, even when bypassed.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Since `\landscape` of `bagpipe.tex` issues `\special{papersize=...}`, you are probably using pdfTeX. There the output paper size for the driver part of pdfTeX is set via the registers `\pdfpagewidth` and `\pdfpageheight`.

- Version for letter paper size:

  ```
  \USletter % optional, default
  \landscape
  \pdfpagewidth=11in
  \pdfpageheight=8.5in
  ```
- Version for A4 paper size:

  ```
  \Afour
  \landscape
  \pdfpagewidth=210mm
  \pdfpageheight=297mm
  ```
- If the document should be compatible (latex/dvips or pdfTeX, ...) then
  package `ifpdf` helps to detect pdfTeX in PDF mode. The package also works in plain TeX:

  ```
  \Afour
  \landscape
  \input ifpdf.sty
  \ifpdf
    \pdfpagewidth=297mm
    \pdfpageheight=210mm
  \fi
  ```